# Check token account balances before and after simulate transaction

Tags: spl-token, transaction, simulate

Let's say you're checking out some simulated transactions, with sigVerify set to false, is there some nice way to print out account balances (SPL token and/or Sol) in the simulated transaction universe before and after the transaction? The program logs only give very cursory information, like the transfer was a success.

```
  const simulationResult = await provider.connection.simulateTransaction(
    transaction,
    {
      sigVerify: false,
    }
  );
```

Maybe there's some handy instruction for printing out balances that exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `pre` and `post` token balances are not included in simulation results unfortunately, the same as they are for `getTransaction`. It might be worth adding those.

In the meantime, you can look through all of the top-level and inner instructions for token transfers, and then reverse them to get the pre balances.

The post balances are included in the `accounts` field from `simulateTransaction`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably add a print my token instruction in a program that you deploy and add the instruction before and after your actual instruction you are interested in.